# What do you use the Android Terminal Emulator for?

Tags: android, terminal

Why is there a terminal emulator in the Android App Market?

Comment: If you are familiar at all with shells, I think it's pretty intuitive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you can get direct access to the commandline?

Android is based on Linux, so it's essentially the Linux commandline you'd be accessing here

If you don't know the Linux commandline:

http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php

Please note that it'll be a somewhat limited environment - you might need to root your phone to get access to everything, also some commands won't be available, you probably want to install something like Busybox to get a more featureful environment.

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

As above - it's for shell access, once you have root.

I've mainly just used it for browsing the file structure to get a better idea of where everything sits.

Comment: Root is not required to make basic usage of it.  In fact, sometimes its quite useful to have a shell that runs with the permissions of an ordinary application in order to see what is/isn't possible from an app (not that you can't create an unprivileged shell from a root shell).

Answer (score 0):

We use terminal emulator on Android for executing Linux core shells or other shells and program like that. It is a very useful app for Android developers.